# Hmmm Assembly Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: recursion, assembly, fibonacci

I need to write and print out the Fibonacci sequence up to a given integer (can choose yourself)
I have to do this in Hmmm... Assembly
It gets stuck in infinite recursion, but I have no idea why

```
00 read r4          # User input
01 setn r4 -1       # adds -1 to r4
02 setn r1 1        # r1 == 1
03 setn r2 0        # r2 == 0
04 setn r5 1        # used as the first number of the fibonacci sequence
05 write r5         # 1
06 jeqzn r4 13      # if r4 == 0, the fibonacci sequence stops
07 add r3 r1 r2     # r3 = r1 + r2
08 addn r4 -1       # r4 = r4 -1 
09 copy r2 r1       # r2 now equals r1
10 copy r1 r3       # r1 nog equals r3
11 write r3         # prints fibonacci number
12 jumpn 06         # checks if r4 == 0
13 halt             # stops
```

current output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
..
..
```

Wanted output (example): if input (r4) = 10

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```

08 addn r4 -1 (r4 should eventually end up being 0)

06 jeqzn r4 13 (should check when it's true, and it should halt)

What prevents it from halting?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like line 1 sets `r4` (the input) to -1 instead of the desired subtracting 1, so it should be `addn r4 -1`.

It's also worth noting the current implementation is iterative and not recursive, and the loop doesn't appear to be infinite but just really long as it would have to count down from -1 to wrap around to 0 (assuming `addn` does not saturate).